# How to have an if/else statement in a computed/methods property block for VueX?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a variable passed into a component called "store". This will store the name of the store that needs to be used in the component. This component just needs to make sure to get the data from the proper store.

```
computed: {
   if (this.store === "storeNumber1")
      ...mapGetters(this.store, ["thing1", "thing2"]),
   else if(this.store === "storeNumber2") 
       ...mapGetters(this.store, ["thing1", "thing2"]),


}
props: {
 store
}
```

This does not work. What would I need to make this concept work? And what about for Vue Mutations? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapGetters` isn't meant to be used in a reactive way based on a `prop`.

Instead, you should use the longhand syntax to access the namespaced getter from the `this.$store.getters` object:

```js
this.$store.getters[__MODULE_NAME__ + '/' + __GETTER_NAME]
```

Use that syntax in a computed property for each getter:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    store: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    thing1() {
      return this.$store.getters[this.store + '/thing1']
    },
    thing2() {
      return this.$store.getters[this.store + '/thing2']
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vuex-computed-getter?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: This worked great. How can I do the same with mutations?

Comment: `this.$store.dispatch(this.store + '/' + __MUTATION_NAME__)`

Comment: How would I use this? Do I just use this in place of the method call? And how would I pass a parameter?

Comment: [Like this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components) , and the parameter will be the second argument of dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this does not work. `computed` properties need to be functions with a simple return. What you want need to be compined between `computed` and `methods`:

```
methods: {
   myFunction() {
      if (this.store === "storeNumber1") {
         return ...mapGetters(this.store, ["thing1", "thing2"])
      }
      else if(this.store === "storeNumber2") {
         return ...mapGetters(this.store, ["thing1", "thing2"])
      }
   }
}

computed: {
   myComputedProperty() {
      return this.myFunction()
   }
}

props: {
 store
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am getitng a syntax error. https://i.imgur.com/JzmwIYW.png

Comment: @tmiliketurtles I´ve edited my answer. Try it out.